# Is it possible to check what extended permissions have been granted by a user?

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm building the option to post to a user's wall into an app. The feature is optional, so I'll need to render my site a little differently depending on whether or not the user has authorised the application or not.

The application is an ASP.NET MVC3 RC2 project using Facebook SDK 4.2.1.

Is this possible through the C# SDK?
Is there a clean(ish) hack to get that info from the SDK?
Or is there a way to retrieve this info (preferably server side) from Facebook directly?

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can do it with FQL.

```
var fbApp = new FacebookApp();
fbApp.Query("select publish_stream from permissions where uid=me()");
```

Rich

Comment: You can also use the Graph API https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=<blah>